# _form partial undefined method `staticpages_path' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Something wrong in my partial:

```
<% form_for(@static) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The edit method:

```
def edit
    @static=Staticpage.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And I use this solution in the routes.rb

```
resources :static
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your model is called Staticpage, but in your routes you only call it static so that does not match. You can solve this in a number of ways. For example:

```
#routes.rb
resources :staticpages
```

If you don't want to do that then you could also manually specify the path in your call to form_for like this:

```
<% form_for(@static, :url => static_path) do |f| %>
```

And also, you could rename your model to Static, but I think that is more complicated solution since it will probably affect a lot of other thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
rake routes
```

in terminal see what's your path,

it could be the routes.rb,
maybe

```
resources :staticpages
```

? just a guess